# Double WHILE loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

The big picture is that I need to extract a bunch of different person data and aggregate it by site.  The final result would look something like this:

```
Site1
   Person1 general info
   Person1 sales info
   Person1 customer info
   Person1 vendor info
   Person2 general info
   Person2 sales info
   Person2 customer info
   Person2 vendor info
   Person3 general info
   .
   .
   .
Site2
   Person1 general info
   Person1 sales info
   Person1 customer info
   Person1 vendor info
   Person2 general info
   Person2 sales info
   Person2 customer info
   Person2 vendor info
   Person3 general info
   .
   .
   .
Site 4
   Person1 general info
  ...etc
```

Each site may or may not have the same people. The sites are all in one table. Each of the 4 categories for the Person info are in individual tables.  The general info is for all people is in table 1 and includes the site number.  The sales info for all people is in table2 and also includes the site number for each.  The customer and vendor information are both in separate tables but only reference the personID of the employee (not site).

Furthermore, in order to bcp out my results, I am taking the result from this query and putting it in a temp table and then appending each into the final text file.

The code that I have here makes the results look like this:

```
Site1
Person1 general info
Person1 sales info
Person1 customer info
Person1 vendor info
Site4
Person2 general info
Person2 sales info
Person2 customer info
Person2 vendor info
Site2
Person3 general info
...etc
```

and here's the code for just one site, one person:

```
DECLARE @salespersonid INT
DECLARE @siteNum VARCHAR(14)
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @rID INT
DECLARE @SQLCmd as VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)

set @count = (select count(*) from tmp_salesSDrec)
set @rID = 1 --because siteid is sequential and unique in tmp_salesSDrec

WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN

set @siteNum = (select siteNumber from tmp_salesSDrec where rID = @rID)

set @salespersonid = (select salespersonid from tmp_sales01rec where rID = @rID)

--drop the tmp_salestemp table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tmp_salestemp]') AND TYPE IN (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tmp_salestemp]

SELECT field1 into tmp_salestemp
FROM
(
     --SDrec
          SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',CAST(LayoutVersion as VARCHAR(3)),',',submissionType,',',salesYear,',',siteType,',',',',',',',',',',','
                              ,CAST(siteCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',',',
                         TPSCode,',',physicalsiteName,',',siteAddr,',',siteCity,',',sicustate,',',siteZip,',',',',',',adminContFirstName,',',adminContLastName,',',
                         adminContPhone,',',adminContEmail,',',techContFirstName,',',techContLastName,',',techContPhone,',',techContEmail,',',CAST(numreports as VARCHAR(4))
                         ,',',CAST(ConversionFactor as VARCHAR(6)),',',',',calTypeCY,',',',',',',calTypeCY1,',',',',',',calTypeCY2,',',',',',',calTypeCY3,',',',',',',',',',',',',','
                              ,CAST(MatchingName as VARCHAR(2)),',',',',
                         extractDate,',',eor)
          as field1, 1 as sortOrder, recordID
          from tmp_salesSDrec
          where siteNumber = @siteNum
  UNION ALL
     --01rec
          SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',',',CAST(siteATPCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',empNumber,',',stateNumber,',',',',',',',',firstName,',',',',lastName
                         ,',',address_1,',',',',city,',',[state],',',zip,',',',',CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dob,112),',',gender,',',salesgrade,',',',',',',salesgraddate,',',',',',',salesrank,',',',',',',',',',',
                         partnerYouth,',',siteConsent,',',eor)
          as field1, 2 as sortOrder, recordID
          from tmp_sales01rec
          where salespersonid = @salespersonid and siteNumber = @siteNum
  UNION ALL
     --02rec
          select CONCAT(recordID,',',salesgrade,',',siteAttended,',',siteATPCode,',',',',salesYear,',',',',term,',',blockSales,',',workInProgress,',',
                         CAST(sectorID as VARCHAR(25)),',',sectorName,',',',',',',',',PrepInd,',',salesAtmpt,',',salesEarned,',',sectorsalesgrade,',',LOWER(area),',',eor)
          as field1, 3 as sortOrder, recordID
          from tmp_sales02rec
          where salespersonid = @salespersonid and siteNumber = @siteNum
    UNION ALL
     --03rec
          select CONCAT(recordID,',',custType,',',custDate,',',subcustName,',',custScore,',',eor)
          as field1, 4 as sortOrder, recordID
          from tmp_sales03rec
          where salespersonid = @salespersonid
    UNION ALL
     --04rec
          select CONCAT(recordID,',',vendorType,',',otherVendorType,',',vendorDate,',',vendorStatus,',',eor)
          as field1, 5 as sortOrder, recordID
          from tmp_sales04rec
          where salespersonid = @salespersonid
) sq
order by sortOrder, recordID;

SELECT @SQLCmd = 'bcp "select * from [sales].dbo.tmp_salestemp" queryout "c:\bcpTemp.csv" -w -t -T -S && type c:\bcpTemp.csv >> c:\sales_2015.csv' ;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd;

     set @rID = @rID + 1;

     set @count = @count - 1;



END
```

I was thinking that I need to add a second while loop in this for each of the salespersonIDs, and then have the original loop for the sites.

Does anyone have any suggestions or a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to write this without any while loops.  It will be much faster using a pure set based query.  Change your query to something like below and export it all in one big batch.

```
SELECT field1 into tmp_salestemp
FROM
(
     --SDrec
          SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',CAST(LayoutVersion as VARCHAR(3)),',',submissionType,',',salesYear,',',siteType,',',',',',',',',',',','
                              ,CAST(siteCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',',',
                         TPSCode,',',physicalsiteName,',',siteAddr,',',siteCity,',',sicustate,',',siteZip,',',',',',',adminContFirstName,',',adminContLastName,',',
                         adminContPhone,',',adminContEmail,',',techContFirstName,',',techContLastName,',',techContPhone,',',techContEmail,',',CAST(numreports as VARCHAR(4))
                         ,',',CAST(ConversionFactor as VARCHAR(6)),',',',',calTypeCY,',',',',',',calTypeCY1,',',',',',',calTypeCY2,',',',',',',calTypeCY3,',',',',',',',',',',',',','
                              ,CAST(MatchingName as VARCHAR(2)),',',',',
                         extractDate,',',eor)
          as field1, 1 as sortOrder, recordID, tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber, convert(int,null) salespersonid
          from tmp_salesSDrec
  UNION ALL
     --01rec
          SELECT CONCAT(recordID,',',',',CAST(siteATPCode as VARCHAR(6)),',',empNumber,',',stateNumber,',',',',',',',',firstName,',',',',lastName
                         ,',',address_1,',',',',city,',',[state],',',zip,',',',',CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dob,112),',',gender,',',salesgrade,',',',',',',salesgraddate,',',',',',',salesrank,',',',',',',',',',',
                         partnerYouth,',',siteConsent,',',eor)
          as field1, 2 as sortOrder, recordID, tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber, salespersonid
          from tmp_sales01rec 
          join tmp_salesSDrec 
          on tmp_sales01rec.siteNumber = tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber
  UNION ALL
     --02rec
          select CONCAT(recordID,',',salesgrade,',',siteAttended,',',siteATPCode,',',',',salesYear,',',',',term,',',blockSales,',',workInProgress,',',
                         CAST(sectorID as VARCHAR(25)),',',sectorName,',',',',',',',',PrepInd,',',salesAtmpt,',',salesEarned,',',sectorsalesgrade,',',LOWER(area),',',eor)
          as field1, 3 as sortOrder, recordID, tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber, salespersonid
          from tmp_sales01rec 
          join tmp_salesSDrec 
          on tmp_sales01rec.siteNumber = tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber
    UNION ALL
     --03rec
          select CONCAT(recordID,',',custType,',',custDate,',',subcustName,',',custScore,',',eor)
          as field1, 4 as sortOrder, recordID, tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber, salespersonid
          from tmp_sales01rec 
          join tmp_salesSDrec 
          on tmp_sales01rec.siteNumber = tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber
    UNION ALL
     --04rec
          select CONCAT(recordID,',',vendorType,',',otherVendorType,',',vendorDate,',',vendorStatus,',',eor)
          as field1, 5 as sortOrder, recordID, tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber, salespersonid
          from tmp_sales01rec 
          join tmp_salesSDrec 
          on tmp_sales01rec.siteNumber = tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber
) sq
order by tmp_salesSDrec.siteNumber, salespersonid, sortOrder, recordID;
```

I don't have any of your data, so I couldn't test this so it might need some tweaking.

Comment: This is terrific, but I am getting the error 
"Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: This error indicates that one or more of the select statements involved in the union query do not have the same number of columns.  All the columns and types much match up.  One problem I just noticed with my query is that in the first select the last field salespersonid doesn't have a type, so you might want to move the first select to the bottom... or make sure that you define the types explicitly in the first select.  I edited my question to add a conversion to the salespersonid.  But that shouldn't cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you Brian.  I accounted for the conversion, but I do have to have different number of expressions for this output...I will keep tinkering.  Thank you for the great start!